# How to trace a computational error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am working on developing a web site that dynamically creates a table and highlights prime numbers for the user at http://www.primenumbertable.com. I thought I had the computational flow mapped out properly, but after I included the ability for the user to include a starting point, something fell apart.

Instead of computing tables to the range specified, tables sometimes get cut short. For instance, if the user specifies that they want to check 100 numbers, and have a starting point of 1, the table will only generate numbers 1-9, instead of 1-100.

I even broke out a pen and pad and tried to do the computations step-by-step myself, to see where the error was coming, but my pen and pad calculations had no computational anomalies.

It seemed to me that the value that was being input was somehow getting the last "0" cut off before going into the table, but i couldn't find how that was happening. Then, I thought that this could not be the problem, because when i try to check 99 numbers, I get a table that goes all the way up to 102!

So, I really have two questions: 1 - How do I trace where the computational error is being made, and 2 - Can anyone see a fix for what is going wrong?

The following is my source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<!-- This page asks the user to input a number to search for primes and returns a base-6 table with primes highlighted -->
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="keywords" content="prime numbers, prime, primes, prime twins">
<title>Prime Numbers</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

/* This function determines if a number is prime or not */
function isPrime(n) {
 if (isNaN(n) || !isFinite(n) || n%1 || n<2) return false; 
 if (n%2==0) return (n==2);
 if (n%3==0) return (n==3);
 var m=Math.sqrt(n);
 for (var i=5;i<=m;i+=6) {
  if (n%i==0)     return false;
  if (n%(i+2)==0) return false;
 }
 return true;
}

/* This function creates the table and color codes the cells of prime numbers */
function tableCreate(X,Y){

    var numCheck = X;           /* assigns numCheck the value the user input for how many numbers are to be checked*/
    var numRow = numCheck/6;    /* assigns the value that will be used as the number of rows in the table. */
    var numCell = Y;            /* assigns the value that will be used in the table cell */
    var body = document.body;   /* assigns the value of the document body */
    var tbl  = document.createElement('table'); /* creates a table dynamically to be filled */
    var highlightColor = document.getElementById('highlight').value; /* assign the value of the color the user requested for highlighting primes */

    if(isNaN(numCheck)==true){
        document.getElementById('tablearea').innerHTML='Please enter a number in arabic numerals.';
        return; /* if the user did not enter a number to check, the function will instruct the user to do so properly. */
    }
    else{
    for(var i = 0; i < numRow; i++){ /*continues the loop until the proper number of rows have been dynamically filled */
        var tr = tbl.insertRow(-1); /* inserts a new row at the bottom */
        for(var j = 0; j < 6; j++){ /*continues the loop until all data cells in the row have been filled */
            if(i==numRow && j==6 || numCheck==(numCell + Y)-1){
                    break
            } 
            else {
                var td = tr.insertCell(-1); /* inserts a new data cell into the row */
                if(isPrime(numCell) == true){ /* calls the function isPrime to test if the number going into the data cell is a prime */
                    if(highlightColor == ''){
                    td.style.backgroundColor='yellow'; /* uses the color yellow to highlight a cell if the user failed to specify a color */
                    }
                    else{
                    td.style.backgroundColor=highlightColor; /* uses the user's choice of color to highlight the cell if the number going in is prime */
                    }
                }
                td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(numCell)); /* prints the number in the data cell */
                numCell++; /* increases the count of the number of numbers checked by 1 */
            }
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('tablearea').innerHTML='';              /* clears any previous tables that were written */
    document.getElementById('tablearea').appendChild(tbl);          /* writes the new table */
    document.getElementById('backtotop').innerHTML="Back to top";   /* puts a 'back to top' link at the bottom */
    document.getElementById('backtotop').href="#top";               /* links the btt link to the top */
}
}
/* This function clears the tablearea when called */
function tableClear(){
    document.getElementById('tablearea').innerHTML='';
    document.getElementById('backtotop').innerHTML='';
}
</script>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
        background-image: url('primesbackground.png');
    }
    h1{
        width: 700px; 
        margin: auto; 
        text-align: center; 
        background-color: white;
    }
    table{
        width: 50%; 
        border: 1px solid black; 
        background-color: gray; 
        position: relative;
    }
    td{
        border: 1px solid black; 
        background-color: white;
    }   
    .parameters{
        float: left; 
        width: 300px; 
        height: 100%; 
        margin: 10px; 
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .tablearea{
        text-align: center; 
        display: inline-block;
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>
<a id="top"></a>
<h1>Welcome to the Prime Number Table Generator.</h1>
<div>
    <div class="parameters">
        <form name="primes">
        <p style="text-align: center; margin: 10px">
        How many numbers would you like to check for primes?<br />
        <input type="text" id="nums"><br />
        What number would you like to use as a starting point?<br />
        <input type="text" id="startpoint"><br />
        What color would you like primes highlighted?<br />
        <input type="text" id="highlight"><br />
        <input type="button" value="Check'em!" onClick="tableCreate(document.primes.nums.value,document.primes.startpoint.value)">
        <input type="reset" onClick="tableClear()"><br />
        To suggest improvements to this site, please send an email to&nbsp;<a href="mailto:webmaster@primenumbertable.com">webmaster@primenumbertable.com</a>.<br />
        </p>
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tablearea" class="tablearea">
    <!-- This area is filled by the function tableCreate() -->
    </div>
    <p style="text-align: center; float: bottom"><a href="" id="backtotop"></a></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: try to use firebug in firefox and check it line by line using the Javascript debugger it seems to have problem with float precision

Comment: I can't use Firefox on the system I am using. Google Chrome is what I am using.

Answer (score 1):

Chrome also has developer tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd>)

It seems to be a problem with your `numRow` property.

```
var numRow = numCheck/6;
```

When `numCheck` is 100, this sets `numRow` to be a floating point number: 16.666666666666668

Later you're checking this value to `break` out of your for loop

```
if(i==numRow && j==6 || numCheck==(numCell + Y)-1){
```

but `i` will never equal numRow because `i` is an integer and `numRow` is a float

I would try and parse numCheck to be an integer using the `parseInt` method by replacing this line

```
var numRow = numCheck/6;
```

with

```
var numRow = parseInt(numCheck/6);
```

Comment: I tried it. It didn't work. I thought when JS did division, it left off everything to the right of the decimal? Also, isn't parseInt() used to convert strings? Would a Math object method work better?

Comment: `parseInt` does take strings, but JS would box the value automatically. You could use `Math.floor(numRow)` if you wanted

Answer (score 0):

Using Google Chrome, you can insert `log` in your JavaScript like this: `console.log("YOUR LOG");`. You can then enter the developer tools (press <kbd>F12</kbd>) and select the `console` tab to check the logs.

I have looked into your code, the main problem lies in the following `if` condition in your `tableCreate` method:

```
if(i==numRow && j==6 || numCheck==(numCell + Y)-1){
    break
}
```

Javascript interprets `numCell` as string, so `numCell + Y` becomes string concatenation. You should force Javascript to perform integer computation to fix your issue:

```
var count = parseInt(numCell) + parseInt(Y) - 1;
if(i==numRow && j==6 || numCheck==count){
    break
}
```

Comment: I suspected something like that, but I couldn't work out where it was. I'll try the solution in the morning and let you know what happens. Thanks.

Comment: After implementing the change above, I get a table starting from `1` to `99` instead of `9`. There are still some minor logically error that you need to fix. By the way, currently you generate the table by running primality test on every single number. It works fine when the table size is small, but the performance will be poor when the table size gets large. You should consider using algorithm such as [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes).